# How to create a map that takes values from other map and then maps them to its field?

Tags: java, collectors

So I have a map of ids to systemUsers and now I want to create a map of systemUser keys and login values. Login is a field inside systemUser class. I have a problem with how to write the mapper functions or even if it's the right way to go about it

```
Map<Long, PHSystemUser> systemUserMap = getPersistenceLogic()
                      .getSystemUsersMap(serviceClientMap.values());

Map<PHSystemUser, String> loginMap = systemUserMap.values().stream()
                      .map(PHSystemUser::getLogin)
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(, ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to collect directly using two functions:

```
systemUserMap.values().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), PHSystemUser::getLogin));
```

The problem with `.map(PHSystemUser::getLogin)` is that it changes the stream to `Stream<String>`, leaving you no chance to have the entire `PHSystemUser` object downstream.